# Recursing through directories: child objects showing up blank?

Tags: json, powershell, recursion

I have a script I'm building to recurse through a file tree, build an object to represent that tree, and print it out in JSON. However, for some reason, the child objects are showing up blank when I try to print them. Here's the code I have so far:

```
$dir = "c:\dell"

# Top-level object to hold the directory tree
$obj = @{}

function recurse($dir, [ref]$obj) {

    write-host "recursing into $dir"

    # Object to hold this subdir & children
    $thisobj = @{}

    # List the files & folders in this directory
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $dir | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true  }
    $files   = Get-ChildItem $dir | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false }

    #write-host $folders

    # Iterate through the subdirs in this directory
    foreach ($f in $folders) {
        # Recurse into this subdir
        recurse $f.fullname ([ref]$thisobj)
    }

    # Iterate through the files in this directory and add them to 
    foreach ($f in $files) {
        write-host " - adding file to thisobj: $f"
        $thisobj | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $f -value 10
    }

    # Print out this subtree
    "$dir thisobj: "
    $thisobj | convertto-json -depth 100

    # Add this subtree to parent obj
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name $dir -value $thisobj

    write-host "finished processing $dir"

}

# Initial recursion
recurse $dir ([ref]$obj)

write-host "final obj:"
$obj | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100
```

Here's what I'm trying to get the final output to look like:

```
{
    "updatepackage": {
        "log": {
            "DELLMUP.log": 5632
        }
        "New Text Document.txt": 0
    }
    "list.csv": 588
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON you want out of this process? I have a feeling that what you've done here is probably more code than is needed.

Comment: Probably, but I wasn't able to find any better way. I've added sample output to the question.

Comment: What should your script achieve?

Comment: `[ref]$obj` -> `$obj`, `[ref]$thisobj` -> `$thisobj`, but personally I would rewrite `recurse` to return object instead of modify one passed by parameters.

Comment: I have a feeling `$Json = gci -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}  | select Name, Length | ConvertTo-Json` where you select on the properties you want does what you want quicker, and more cleanly...

Comment: @AustinFrench that flattens the tree; the ultimate goal is to import the json into a treemap to generate a WinDirStat-like chart on remote systems

Comment: So why not select the parent path as part of the json?

Comment: @AustinFrench the tree would still be flat

Comment: But you could easily rebuild the tree off of the parent path. For example c:/ the c:/users and c:/users/profilea/

Comment: More specifically, the attribute would be Directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you better to rewrite `recurse` to return object representing directory rather than modify one passed by parameter:

```
function recurse {
    param($Dir)

    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Dir |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Obj = [ordered]@{}
    } {
        $Obj.Add($_.PSChildName, $(
            if($_.PSIsContainer) {
                recurse $_.PSPath
            } else {
                $_.Length
            }
        ))
    } {
        $Obj
    }
}

recurse c:\dell | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

Comment: That produces the output I want. Can you explain the syntax of how you used ForEach-Object?

Comment: @wmassingham `1..3 | ForEach-Object { 'Begin' } { "Process $_" } { 'End' }` I just use all three (`Begin`, `Process` and `End`) blocks rather just only `Process` block.